# Homological and homotopical equivalence of complex analytic varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Consider a map between two complex analytic varieties of finite type $f:X\to Y$. Suppose that $f$ induces isomorphisms on cohomology with (constant) integral coefficients. Under what reasonable hypotheses can we conclude that it induces an equivalence on homotopy groups?

I refer in particular to this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.05366.pdf, Proof of proposition 3.17 on page 14, where the Authors use a result of this kind. I cannot understand why classical hypotheses like nilpotency of the spaces are verified.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Posted in MO as https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354801/homological-and-homotopical-equivalence-of-complex-analytic-varieties

Comment: Have you considered asking the authors of that paper? I'm not aware of any special conditions that would apply to complex analytic varieties but not arbitrary spaces (but this may just be a failure of my knowledge).

Comment: Not yet. I was hoping to find something on my own, but if this does not work I will.

Comment: As a question about the technical details of a new research paper, which as you note can’t obviously be resolved using the best known relevant techniques, I’d be hard pressed to imagine this wouldn’t meet MO’s standards.

Comment: This smells like it ought be a combination of the fact that it's easy to get a CW complex  structure on the $\Bbb C$-points of a variety plus various results of the sort that a homology isomorphism plus a condition on $\pi_1$ gives a weak equivalence, which on CW complexes is actually a homotopy equivalence. (If you're wondering about nilpotency, which I don't see in the proof but probably missed, [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55260/reference-needed-isomorphism-on-pi-1-and-homology-gives-weak-equivalence) answer has a hint in that direction.) Posting on MO would probably be fine!

Comment: Indeed, it would suffice to know that the \pi_1 is abelian. This would prove that the \pi_1 coincide via the given map and thus we can apply the answer you posted.